# Why can't I get all my core data fetch results into a UILabel?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, uilabel

I have this code, when I use print command, I can get all of my fetch results, but if I tried to put the results inside a UILabel and display it, only the lasted inserted value shows.

```
do {
        let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "date") as! String)
            print(data.value(forKey: "score") as! String)
            var x = data.value(forKey: "date") as! String
            var y = data.value(forKey: "score") as! String


            //allScores.text = "Session started on \(x), points earned:  \(y)"
        }
    } catch  {
         print("Failed")
    }
```

Doing this works,

```
print(data.value(forKey: "date") as! String)
            print(data.value(forKey: "score") as! String)
```

but this doesn't it only shows last inserted value in my UILabel

```
var x = data.value(forKey: "date") as! String
var y = data.value(forKey: "score") as! String 

allScores.text = "Session started on \(x), points earned:  \(y)"
```

Comment: You are setting the label text in your for loop. That means the loop will run till it reaches last value. Thats why you are getting only last score. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to get all my data and put it in a UILabel not just the last score

Comment: You want to show all data in just one label?

Comment: ya all of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
do {
        let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        allScores.text = ""
        for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
            print(data.value(forKey: "date") as! String)
            print(data.value(forKey: "score") as! String)
            var x = data.value(forKey: "date") as! String
            var y = data.value(forKey: "score") as! String


            allScores.text = (allScores.text ?? "")  + "Session started on \(x), points earned:  \(y)"
        }
    } catch  {
         print("Failed")
    }
```

Comment: also make sure  to do this: allScores.numberOfLines = 0 
so that the label can expand to multiple lines

Comment: there is a right sign in front of my answer. which is visible to you only.

Comment: you can't upvote the answer until you does not have a 15 and more points.

Comment: I just realised that if my database only has 1 record, using yr method doesn't show the first record on my UILabel, only after I insert the second record then the first and second records shows in the UIlabel. The print command shows the first record though.

Comment: Nevemind, it my mistake,only after I added allScores.numberOfLines = 0; &&[allScores .sizeToFit()];  to format my UILabel then its happens